# Android Google Maps V2 - On Camera moving Event

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I think my question is already obvious - I wish for a listener everytime the map Camera is changing.

I already had on Touch event, on Dragged Event. However, I cannot catch the event when the map is moving (example, I strongly swipe the Google maps and the map is moving co-related to the force I exerted without my finger on the screen anymore. )

Please help.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Does the [`onCameraChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener.html) suit your needs?

If not, could you pass touch events to a gesture detector to detect all scrolls and flings manually, then manually control the corresponding map animation by repeatedly updating the map camera position?

Comment: Thanks stkentt but it doesn't. `onCameraChangeListener` only triggers when the map camera stops from moving. What I want is every millisecond (if necessary) the map camera moves.

Comment: Again @stkentt thanks. However, Gesture Detector seems to only be triggered once or twice for every gesture detected (well, maybe as its terms pronounce, `gesture detector`). So if I swipe it to left, the gesture detector will trigger only once/twice. Well, that's as far as how I understood the code I created (this is how I tried to implement gesture detection http://stackoverflow.com/a/938657/1664424)

What I simply need is an event that catches every movement the Google Map camera do.

Comment: Hmm, I'm stumped then I'm afraid!